# PHP getting a variable from another .php file

Tags: php, inheritance

I'm Alex and I am learning PHP. I have two files named.. file1.php and file2.php. I have a variable inside file1.php and I want to refer it in file2.php, how can I do that? I know it's a stupid question for most of you but I'm new to this and I'm trying to learn. Thank you in advance, I'll provide you with my code.

File1.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $passwordmd5 = md5($password);

    if(!empty($username) && !empty($password)){

        $query = "SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$passwordmd5'";

        if($queryrun = mysql_query($query)){
            $query_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($queryrun);
            if($query_num_rows == 0){
                echo 'Invalid username and password';
            } else if($query_num_rows == 1){
                echo $user_id = mysql_result($queryrun, 0, 'id');
                $_SESSION['user_id']=$user_id;
                header('Location: index.php' . $username);
            }
        }  else {
            echo 'Enter a username and a password';
        }
    }

?>
```

File2.php

```
<?php
        require 'core.php';
        require 'connectdb.php';

        if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && !empty($_SESSION['user_id'])){
            echo '<a href = "logout.php"><input type = "submit" id = "logreg" value = "Logout" /></a>';
        }else{
            echo '<a href = "loginregister.php"><input type = "submit" id = "logreg" value = "Login/Register" /></a>';
        }
    ?>
```

Basically, File1.php is a login form for a website and I am entering a username and submit it, if I succesfully submit it and I login, I want my button to change from "Login/Register" to "Welcome, ", how can I do that?
On a short note, how can I transfer my $username variable that I enter in my File1.php to File2.php?
For example.. I press the Login/Register button, I type in Alex as a username and 123 as password and press the Login button. (That to be done in file1.php) Considering the user and the password being correct, I am moving to file2.php and instead of the Login/Register button, I want a new button, or a div (whatever) to show up with the text "Welcome, Alex" or "Welcome, -username-". How can I do that?

Comment: Protip: I wouldn't waste my time with this if I were you. You're playing with fire using a deprecated MySQL function and a password storage system that is broken.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Can you elaborate?

Comment: [`mysql_query`](http://uk1.php.net/mysql_query) and that whole set of functions is deprecated. You should use [`PDO`](http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) instead.

`md5` is not secure for passwords. In php 5.5 there is a [password hashing api](http://www.sitepoint.com/hashing-passwords-php-5-5-password-hashing-api/) which is basically bcrypt, or you can use a proper password hashing library.

Comment: @Max Thank you, I will keep this in mind. For this project (college project and I'm on a deadline) I will use these functions.. but for future references I will use the new ones, thank you again for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include session_start on your file2.php code.  If file1.php isn't the first page you will need to add the session_start at the beginning of it as well.

```
<?php
   session_start();
    require 'core.php';
    require 'connectdb.php';

    if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && !empty($_SESSION['user_id'])){
        echo '<a href = "logout.php"><input type = "submit" id = "logreg" value = "Logout" /></a>';
    }else{
        echo '<a href = "loginregister.php"><input type = "submit" id = "logreg" value = "Login/Register" /></a>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Does not answer my question.. I want to take the $username variable from my file1.php and transfer it to file2.php. For example.. I press the Login/Register button, I type in Alex as a username and 123 as password and press the Login button. (That to be done in file1.php) Considering the user and the password being correct, I am moving to file2.php and instead of the Login/Register button, I want a new button, or a div (whatever) to show up with the text "Welcome, Alex" or "Welcome, <username>". How can I do that?

Comment: File1.php  $_SESSION['id']= $username;

Comment: Then in File2.php add the line $username = $_SESSION['id'];

Comment: You must understand that everything that File1.php knew, dies once the executiom completes. When you "move" (as you say) to File2.php, everything you did in file1 is gone, dead, forgotten. As far as PHP is concerned, those are two separate requests, two separate executions. If you want to keep whatever you did in file1 and use it later, you must save if somewhere (persistent) where file2 can read it from. The handiest place for you is the allmighty session. The code above does actually solve your issue.